# Tell if device is running a MIUI software

Tags: android, runtime-permissions, miui

I need to know if my app is running on a MIUI device like XIAOMI at runtime due to issues like pre android 6.0 permissions etc.

Is there a way to to do it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found a gist on github that aims to do just that, by trying to fetch the "ro.miui.ui.version.name" system property.

```
public static boolean isMiUi() {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(getSystemProperty("ro.miui.ui.version.name"));
}

public static String getSystemProperty(String propName) {
    String line;
    BufferedReader input = null;
    try {
        java.lang.Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop " + propName);
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()), 1024);
        line = input.readLine();
        input.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (input != null) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return line;
}
```

[Origin on github](https://gist.github.com/Muyangmin/e8ec1002c930d8df3df46b306d03315d)

Comment: how check if version MIUI is greather or equals to 11? I don't add this information in this method (that worked as expected to me)